# Why Mother Sīta is shown holding lotus in Her left hand?

Tags: ramayana, sita

In almost all representations of Mother Sita with Lord Rama, She is shown with a lotus in her left hand. As evident in the following images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

While it can be explained why Sri Rama is shown with Bow and Arrow and Lord Hanuman is shown with mace(gada), but what is the significance of lotus in Mother Sita's hand?

Comment: Not just Sita devi. ALL devis in any temple, atleast traditional south indian ones hold padma in left hand - https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fc/07/30/fc0730be245a487cbbf9e7eb20add488.jpg, https://www.myangadi.com/image/cache/catalog/ma7tp/ma7tp237-perumal-sridevi-bhudevi-tanjore-painting-classic-frame-550x550h.jpg . Bhagavan has weapons to protect and punish, but Devis only have karuna/vatsalya. The mudras that Bhagavan shows in each temple has separate meaning associated. For Devis, it is mainly Abhaya (meaning, don't be afraid of this guy standing next to me).

Comment: lotus represents Vikasana Shakti. Rama is Purusha/Brahman, Sita is Prakriti/Shakti that expands and manifests as different beings.

Comment: @mar really? Idk if Mother Radha and other Devis hold Lotus. Though Mother Laxmi holds Lotus as far as I remember.

Comment: @TheDestroyer why other Devis like Mother Radha don't hold Lotus then? I think even Mother Laxmi holds Lotus.